# PyKDE4 documentation

Tags: python, pykde

I'm trying to get started using Python for KDE development. What is the canonical source for PyKDE4 reference documentation? The [Python](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Python) page of KDE TechBase is surprisingly sparse on details, and googling hasn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://api.kde.org/pykde-4.3-api/allclasses.html).

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but that's for KDE 4.2. What about 4.3?

Comment: You change the version number in the url :) Edited.